# App listing submission problem on Shopify

Tags: php, wordpress, shopify, shopify-app

I tried to submit the app on shopify for approval. But everytime they give me below message

**Your primary app listing has 2 issues to fix before you can submit your app for review**

> App must set security headers to protect against clickjacking.
> App must verify the authenticity of the request from Shopify.

Here is my code for verifing hmac and its working correctly.

```
$calculated_hmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $data, Auth::$client_secret);
$result = hash_equals($hmac, $calculated_hmac);
```

Here is header I hook on wordpress

`add_action('send_headers', [$this, 'send_headers']);`

```
public function send_headers() {
    header("Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'none';");
    header('X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN');
}
```

But after submitting I am still getting same message.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the CSP wrong. If you check the most recent documentation it is such that the iframe has to exist inside the myshopify.com store domain. Also, has nothing to do with Wordpress. But anyway, ensure your CSP headers you render for frame ancestors are:

```
  "https://someshop.myshopify.com https://admin.shopify.com"
```

With that, your clickjacking problem goes away. For the HMAC, you'll have to try and figure out where you're missing verification. I think they trick you, and you fail to send a 401, telling them you are doing the HMAC right.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did like this for sending 401 error 
if ($verify !== true) {
            return http_response_code(401);
        }